# I have ng-grid and columns in that I have field country id, but I want to print country name in cell. So how can I do that?

Tags: ng-grid

I have ng-grid. Inside that I have bind some columns which is firstname, last name, country, state city.
Actually in country, state, city columns I have stored IDs in table, but on the base of ID I want to print country name.  How is this possible?

Comment: What kind of ids? Where do the country names come from? A db or an array? Plz show us some more data.

Comment: country name comes from db. it is master table for country same state and city also comes from db..
data which i populate in ng-grid comes from user table which store countryID, stateID and cityID..

Comment: Assuming that you have a mySQL db you could JOIN the names in your query on the server side. Or, on the client side, you could use celltemplates and a filter. I would prefer the first solution as it allows way better sorting and filtering.

Answer (score 0):

```js
{ field: 'City', displayName: 'ישוב', cellTemplate: '<div> {{getCityName(row.getProperty(col.field))}}</div>' },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be nice if you could [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27836077/edit) your answer and add some explanation. Code-only answers should be improved.